# Working with standard input in terminal instead of using text file

Tags: c, terminal, stdin

I have a following problem: I am quite a beginner with C and a total beginner to linux terminal (I use fedora) and unix systems. I want to make a program with a table as input. The table should be given as standard input and the program should do several operations with the table such as printing chosen columns and rows, minimum of them maximum etc.

If I run with `<table.txt` everything is fine, but if I run program like this: `./program some parameters ENTER` and then a type the table, program is doing everything but not what I want of it. And my question is: how can I work with terminal like with text file? I mean I want to type a row eith some columns, press enter, another row, enter......then type EOF (think it ctrl + D) ...and the program starts working after the table is finished (ctrl + D) is pressed.

Comment: If I run with <table.txt everything is fine, but if I run program like this: ./program some parameters ENTER and then a type the table, program is doing everything but not what I want of it. And my question is: how can I work with terminal like with text file? I mean I want to type a row eith some columns, press enter, another row, enter......then type EOF (think it ctrl + D) ...and the program starts working after the table is finished (ctrl + D) is pressed. Sorry for long question but my problem is so huge for me that I can not even tell it in a few simple sentences. Thank you for your help

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: What you've described sounds like it should work.  A minimal sample program that works and shows what you're doing in a minimal way would be helpful to understand if something is really wrong.

Comment: It is working well now, there was something wrong in how the program got EOF. It was different when I was working with normal stdin and with <table.txt